# GUI elements doesn't appear properly

Tags: java, swing

Why doesn't the interface appears as it's written !
Whenever I try to add an element to the Jpanlel named p1!
What should I change to get the elements in the specified position?
 I didn't change anything !

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.util.Calendar;
 import javax.swing.JSpinner;
 import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
 import java.text.*;


 public class MyJFrame extends  JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
    private JLabel dur;
    private JButton jButton1;
    private JLabel jLabel1;
    private JLabel jLabel2;
    private JLabel jLabel3;
    private JLabel jLabel4;
    private JLabel jLabel5;
    private JLabel jLabel6;
    private JPanel jPanel1;
    private JSpinner.DateEditor de2;
    private JPanel jPanel2;
    private JPanel jPanel3;
    private JPanel jPanel4;
    private JPanel jPanel5;
    private JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
    private JRadioButton jRadioButton6;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private JSpinner jSpinner1;
    private JSpinner jSpinner2;
    private JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    private JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private JTextField jTextField1;
    private JRadioButton jYes;
    private JRadioButton rb1;
    private JRadioButton rb2;
    private JRadioButton rb3;
    private JTextField txt;
    private JSpinner spp2;
    private Date dat;
    private Date dat2;
    private JLabel jLabel8;
    private JTextArea jTextArea8;
    private JTextField jTextField8;
    private JButton jButton8;  
    private JButton jButton82; 
    private JButton jButton83;   
    private JLabel jLabel82;




  public MyJFrame(){
  JPanel p1=new JPanel();

  JPanel p2=new JPanel();
  JPanel p3=new JPanel();
  JPanel p4=new JPanel();
    //User r;
  jRadioButton6 = new JRadioButton();
  jPanel5 = new JPanel();
  buttonGroup1 = new ButtonGroup();
  buttonGroup2 = new ButtonGroup();

  jLabel1 = new JLabel("Event Title:");
  JTextField tit = new JTextField();       
  jLabel2 = new JLabel("Event Description:");
  JTextArea des = new JTextArea();        
  jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
  jLabel3 = new JLabel("Start date:");
  jLabel4 = new JLabel("End date:");

  Date date = new Date();
  SpinnerDateModel sp = new SpinnerDateModel(date,null,null,Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  JSpinner spp = new JSpinner(sp);

  jSpinner1 = new JSpinner(sp);
  JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(jSpinner1,"dd/mm/yyyy");
  jSpinner1.setEditor(de);



  Date date1 = new Date();
  SpinnerDateModel sp1 = new SpinnerDateModel       (date1,null,null,Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  JSpinner spp3 = new JSpinner(sp1);
  spp2 = new javax.swing.JSpinner(sp1);
  de2 = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spp2,"dd/mm/yyyy");
  spp2.setEditor(de2);

  jLabel5 = new JLabel("Is it a Recurrent event?");
  jYes = new JRadioButton("Yes");
  jRadioButton2 = new JRadioButton("No");
  buttonGroup1 = new ButtonGroup();
  buttonGroup2 = new ButtonGroup();        
  buttonGroup2.add(jYes);
  buttonGroup2.add(jRadioButton2);

  rb1 = new JRadioButton("Daily");
  rb2 = new JRadioButton("Weekly");
  rb3 = new JRadioButton("Monthly");
  buttonGroup1.add(rb1);
  buttonGroup1.add(rb2);
  buttonGroup1.add(rb3);
  dur = new JLabel("Duration:");
  txt = new JTextField();
  jButton1 = new JButton("Add Event");
  jTabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane();
  jPanel1 = new JPanel();
  jPanel3 = new JPanel();
  jPanel4 = new JPanel();
  jPanel2 = new JPanel();
  jLabel6 = new JLabel();
  jLabel8 = new JLabel("Event ID:");
  jTextArea8 = new JTextArea(); 
  jTextField8= new JTextField();
  jButton8=new JButton("Find");
  jButton82=new JButton("Cancel"); 
  jButton83=new JButton("Save Agenda");
  jLabel82 = new JLabel();


  Container contentpane;
  contentpane=getContentPane();
  setSize(600,800);
  setLocation(600,140);
  JPanel tt=new JPanel();
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
  tt.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  getContentPane().add(tt);
  JTabbedPane tabbedPAne=new JTabbedPane();
  tabbedPAne.add("find event",p1);
  tabbedPAne.add("add event",p2);
  tabbedPAne.add("reminders",p3);
  tabbedPAne.add("save&load",p4);
  tt.add(tabbedPAne,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  p2.setLayout(null);
  jLabel1.setBounds(150,80,90,20);
  p2.add(jLabel1);
  tit.setBounds(240,80,170,20);
  p2.add(tit);
  jLabel2.setBounds(100,190,140,20);
  p2.add(jLabel2);
  des.setBounds(240,140,170,140);
  p2.add(des);
  jLabel3.setBounds(150,340,90,20);
  p2.add(jLabel3);
  jSpinner1.setBounds(240,340,160,20);
  p2.add(jSpinner1);
  jLabel4.setBounds(150,390,90,20);
  p2.add(jLabel4);
  spp2.setBounds(240,390,160,20);
  p2.add(spp2);        
  jLabel5.setBounds(120,450,190,20);
  p2.add(jLabel5);
  jYes.setBounds(300,450,50,20);
  jRadioButton2.setBounds(360,450,90,20);
  p2.add(jYes);
  p2.add(jRadioButton2);
  rb1.setBounds(140,500,60,20);
  rb2.setBounds(240,500,70,20);
  rb3.setBounds(340,500,70,20);
  p2.add(rb1);
  p2.add(rb2);
  p2.add(rb3);
  dur.setBounds(155,550,60,20);
  p2.add(dur);
  txt.setBounds(240,550,170,20);
  p2.add(txt);
  rb1.setEnabled(false);
  rb2.setEnabled(false);
  rb3.setEnabled(false);
  dur.setEnabled(false);
  txt.setEnabled(false);
  jButton1.setBounds(250,630,100,20);
  p2.add(jButton1);
        jLabel8.setBounds(90,30,60,20);
  p1.add(jLabel8);
  jTextField8.setBounds(80,30,45,20);
  p1.add(jTextArea8);
  jTextArea8.setBounds(100,80,130,70);
  p1.add(jTextArea8);
  jButton83.setBounds(30,510,50,20);
  p1.add(jButton83);
  jButton8.setBounds(100,45,50,20);
  p1.add(jButton8);
  jButton82.setBounds(90,45,50,20);
  p1.add(jButton82);
  jLabel82.setBounds(230,250,100,300);
  p1.add(jLabel82);

  setTitle("Tests' Planner");
  jYes.addActionListener(this); 
  jButton1.addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: I am using the same code but it doesn't work !

Comment: By default a panel uses a `FlowLayout`. So components are placed on a line one after the other and will wrap to the next line. The setBounds(..) statement do nothing as the layout manager will control everything. If you don't like the way a FlowLayout works, then use a different layout manager, or nest panels with different layout managers to get your desired layout. Learn how to use layout managers effectively by playing with the examples from the above tutorial links.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the main method and setting the JFrame to visible. It's working now. 
Almost all of the components you added use the .setBounds method. Which sets them in a certain position of the frame. You can try changing their parameters in order to change the Component position. Anyway I would recommend using Layouts so that the components will auto fit. You can learn more about layouts here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;

import java.text.*;


public class MyJFrame extends  JFrame implements ActionListener {

private ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
private ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
private JLabel dur;
private JButton jButton1;
private JLabel jLabel1;
private JLabel jLabel2;
private JLabel jLabel3;
private JLabel jLabel4;
private JLabel jLabel5;
private JLabel jLabel6;
private JPanel jPanel1;
private JSpinner.DateEditor de2;
private JPanel jPanel2;
private JPanel jPanel3;
private JPanel jPanel4;
private JPanel jPanel5;
private JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
private JRadioButton jRadioButton6;
private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private JSpinner jSpinner1;
private JSpinner jSpinner2;
private JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
private JTextArea jTextArea1;
private JTextField jTextField1;
private JRadioButton jYes;
private JRadioButton rb1;
private JRadioButton rb2;
private JRadioButton rb3;
private JTextField txt;
private JSpinner spp2;
private Date dat;
private Date dat2;
private JLabel jLabel8;
private JTextArea jTextArea8;
private JTextField jTextField8;
private JButton jButton8;  
private JButton jButton82; 
private JButton jButton83;   
private JLabel jLabel82;




public MyJFrame(){
    JPanel p1=new JPanel();

    JPanel p2=new JPanel();
    JPanel p3=new JPanel();
    JPanel p4=new JPanel();
    //User r;
    jRadioButton6 = new JRadioButton();
    jPanel5 = new JPanel();
    buttonGroup1 = new ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup2 = new ButtonGroup();

    jLabel1 = new JLabel("Event Title:");
    JTextField tit = new JTextField();       
    jLabel2 = new JLabel("Event Description:");
    JTextArea des = new JTextArea();        
    jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
    jLabel3 = new JLabel("Start date:");
    jLabel4 = new JLabel("End date:");

    Date date = new Date();
    SpinnerDateModel sp = new SpinnerDateModel(date,null,null,Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    JSpinner spp = new JSpinner(sp);

    jSpinner1 = new JSpinner(sp);
    JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(jSpinner1,"dd/mm/yyyy");
    jSpinner1.setEditor(de);



    Date date1 = new Date();
    SpinnerDateModel sp1 = new SpinnerDateModel       (date1,null,null,Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    JSpinner spp3 = new JSpinner(sp1);
    spp2 = new javax.swing.JSpinner(sp1);
    de2 = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spp2,"dd/mm/yyyy");
    spp2.setEditor(de2);

    jLabel5 = new JLabel("Is it a Recurrent event?");
    jYes = new JRadioButton("Yes");
    jRadioButton2 = new JRadioButton("No");
    buttonGroup1 = new ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup2 = new ButtonGroup();        
    buttonGroup2.add(jYes);
    buttonGroup2.add(jRadioButton2);

    rb1 = new JRadioButton("Daily");
    rb2 = new JRadioButton("Weekly");
    rb3 = new JRadioButton("Monthly");
    buttonGroup1.add(rb1);
    buttonGroup1.add(rb2);
    buttonGroup1.add(rb3);
    dur = new JLabel("Duration:");
    txt = new JTextField();
    jButton1 = new JButton("Add Event");
    jTabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane();
    jPanel1 = new JPanel();
    jPanel3 = new JPanel();
    jPanel4 = new JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new JPanel();
    jLabel6 = new JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new JLabel("Event ID:");
    jTextArea8 = new JTextArea(); 
    jTextField8= new JTextField();
    jButton8=new JButton("Find");
    jButton82=new JButton("Cancel"); 
    jButton83=new JButton("Save Agenda");
    jLabel82 = new JLabel();


    Container contentpane;
    contentpane=getContentPane();
    setSize(600,800);
    setLocation(600,140);
    JPanel tt=new JPanel();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    tt.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    getContentPane().add(tt);
    JTabbedPane tabbedPAne=new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPAne.add("find event",p1);
    tabbedPAne.add("add event",p2);
    tabbedPAne.add("reminders",p3);
    tabbedPAne.add("save&load",p4);
    tt.add(tabbedPAne,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    p2.setLayout(null);
    jLabel1.setBounds(150,80,90,20);
    p2.add(jLabel1);
    tit.setBounds(240,80,170,20);
    p2.add(tit);
    jLabel2.setBounds(100,190,140,20);
    p2.add(jLabel2);
    des.setBounds(240,140,170,140);
    p2.add(des);
    jLabel3.setBounds(150,340,90,20);
    p2.add(jLabel3);
    jSpinner1.setBounds(240,340,160,20);
    p2.add(jSpinner1);
    jLabel4.setBounds(150,390,90,20);
    p2.add(jLabel4);
    spp2.setBounds(240,390,160,20);
    p2.add(spp2);        
    jLabel5.setBounds(120,450,190,20);
    p2.add(jLabel5);
    jYes.setBounds(300,450,50,20);
    jRadioButton2.setBounds(360,450,90,20);
    p2.add(jYes);
    p2.add(jRadioButton2);
    rb1.setBounds(140,500,60,20);
    rb2.setBounds(240,500,70,20);
    rb3.setBounds(340,500,70,20);
    p2.add(rb1);
    p2.add(rb2);
    p2.add(rb3);
    dur.setBounds(155,550,60,20);
    p2.add(dur);
    txt.setBounds(240,550,170,20);
    p2.add(txt);
    rb1.setEnabled(false);
    rb2.setEnabled(false);
    rb3.setEnabled(false);
    dur.setEnabled(false);
    txt.setEnabled(false);
    jButton1.setBounds(250,630,100,20);
    p2.add(jButton1);
    jLabel8.setBounds(90,30,60,20);
    p1.add(jLabel8);
    jTextField8.setBounds(80,30,45,20);
    p1.add(jTextArea8);
    jTextArea8.setBounds(100,80,130,70);
    p1.add(jTextArea8);
    jButton83.setBounds(30,510,50,20);
    p1.add(jButton83);
    jButton8.setBounds(100,45,50,20);
    p1.add(jButton8);
    jButton82.setBounds(90,45,50,20);
    p1.add(jButton82);
    jLabel82.setBounds(230,250,100,300);
    p1.add(jLabel82);

    setTitle("Tests' Planner");
    jYes.addActionListener(this); 
    jButton1.addActionListener(this); }




@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyJFrame().setVisible(true);;
}
```

}